# Trouble installing pygame from a wheel file

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, python

I'm trying to install pygame(x64) from a .whl file with pip. 
but the cmd gives me this error:

[image]

(This is the source of the wheel file: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)
As you can see in the screenshot, I have downloaded the version of pygame for Python 2.7 x64.
I work on Windows 8.1. The command is running as administrator.

Comment: The last line says "no such file". Have you tried running this command from the folder you're supposed to, rather from c:\windows\system32?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is suggested by the error message you received. `pip` being the continually updated program that it is, you got a message that said:

```
You are using pip version 6.0.8, however version 7.1.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

After you do this, run the command:

```
python -m pip install wheel  
python -m pip install C:/Users/your-username/Downloads/pygame-1.9.2a0-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl
```

This command makes these two assumptions:

1. You have downloaded the `pygame-1.9.2a0-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl` file to your Downloads folder or you have a copy of the `pygame-1.9.2a0-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl` file in your Downloads folder.
2. Replace the string `your-username` with your own username in the above command.

Or `cd` to where you've downloaded the `pygame-1.9.2a0-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl` file and use:

```
python -m pip install wheel  
python -m pip install pygame-1.9.2a0-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl
```